# Unknown type 'CGFLoat'. Did you mean 'CGFloat"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image]

The popup issues is not very descriptive. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Show what files are being `#import`ed.

Comment: I get similar ones occasionally: `Missing ; insert it?` .. in the middle of a word *shrugs*

Comment: how is that not descriptive!? it tells you exactly that `CGFLoat` is not a type name and that you probably mean `CGFloat`

Comment: zbMax spotted the issue. The very subtle typeo `l` vs `L` in `CGFloat`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: @Genu: Why did you not just click on "Fix-it", as offered by Xcode?

Comment: This should stay. That happens to others also. In fact it happened to me. deanWombourne's answer is also a helpful addition and shows where CGFloat comes from and what to import.

Comment: This may have seemed "obvious" or "just a typo" but I don't agree with the downvotes.  If the OP _had_ "just clicked Fix-It", Xcode would not have _explained_ what the issue was exactly and the OP would not have _learned_ anything.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You just have a `L` instead of `l` for `CGFloat`

Comment: It's not that. I've seen this issue happening on Xcode 13 but not 14.

Comment: It's really about `UIKit` not being imported. For some reason, if not importing it on Xcode 13 it's a build error while Xcode 14 allows it.

Comment: Question have been edited since it was asked. The issue really was a typo ("CGFLoat" instead of "CGFloat")

Answer (score 67):

What is imported into this file?

I suspect either

(a) CGFloat isn't imported but XCode is being 'helpful'

or

(b) CGFloat has been defined twice somewhere.

My money is on (a). `CGFloat` is part of core graphics, pulled in with UIKit so you need `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` somewhere in there.

Comment: I was missing #import UIKit. Thanks

Comment: I think this is the third time in my life that this happens and I don't have any clue what's going on. It is always because I want to access objects from the `UIKit` inside an `NSObject`!
Great Answer, thx!